# Prioritizing I/O in LXC on Debian (without LXD)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, lxc, debian-jessie

I had a couple machines where I used OpenVZ and recently, on newer versions of Debian (Jessie), I've been using LXC.

I need a way of giving one container priority on host I/O resources, I could do this on OpenVZ and I find that I can do this with LXD only (which from what I know, only works on Ubuntu) with:

lxc config set my-container limits.disk.priority 10

But as Debian doesn't have LXD, is there a way I can prioritize I/O using LXC in Debian Jessie?

Answer (score 0):

As `LXD` is just a "frontend" for / to `LXC`, this is not really a question about `LXD`.

Actually this is done (in the background) via [control groups (cgroups)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), which is a

> Linux kernel feature that limits, accounts for, and isolates the resource usage (CPU, memory, disk I/O, network, etc.) of a collection of processes.

and leveraging the [blkio subsystem](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Subsystems_and_Tunable_Parameters.html#sec-blkio) which

> controls and monitors access to I/O on block devices by tasks in cgroups. Writing values to some of these pseudofiles limits access or bandwidth, and reading values from some of these pseudofiles provides information on I/O operations.

should give you your expected results.

There are multiple parameters which are tuneable, for details have a look at [the documentation at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt) as well. [Over here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_control_containers.html) you'll find specific examples related to `LXC`.